# subtracting datetime fields

Tags: python, django

I've spent the good part of the last 3 hours searching and I just can't seem to figure out why my code won't work.

```
import datetime
#get time since last status change
@property
def last_update(self):
    if self.statuschange_set.exists():
        last_change = self.statuschange_set.all()[0]
        return last_change.date_changed - self.created
    #if no status change has occurred, use creation date
    if not self.statuschange_set.exists():
        df = DateFormat(datetime.now())
        df = df.format("d/m/Y, P ") 
        return df - self.created
    return ""
```

The code breaks at the bottom where I'm trying to subtract todays date from the creation date. I tested it where I'm able to subtract self.created from itself however the code above spits out an exception value:

```
 Exception Value:   
 unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

I've obviously got the formating wrong of df wrong however even from looking at the other solutions on stackoverflow,  I'm unable to come up with a solution to my issue.

Comment: Just a side note: are you aware of `else:`? It might be possible to avoid checking `self.statuschange_set.exists()` twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting makes no sense, you can just keep it as a datetime

```
return datetime.now() - self.created
```

If you really need the formatting, you should do this *after* the calculation

```
df = DateFormat(datetime.now() - self.created)
...
return df
```